# Call android method (sdk, aar or jar) from nativescript

Tags: android, jar, sdk, aar, nativescript-angular

I need to develop a **nativescript** app integrated with a **sdk android native.**

I created a sample app in android studio and generated a **aar** file, then  I build a nativescript plugin using this file.

Finally I included that plugin in nativescript app.

When I tried to access the method exposed in **aar** file, I got a message saying that the method is not a function.

The first time I tried to create an aar with the following class

**(Java)**

```
package com.example.toasterlibrary;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToasterMessage {
    public ToasterMessage() {
    }

    public static void show(Context c,String message){
       Toast.makeText(c,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then tried changing the "show" function so that it is not static

**(Java)**

```
public void show(Context context, String message) {
    CharSequence text = "Hello NativeScript!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

By the other hand I built a plugin to call the sdk and I got an error message in de index.js file included in the nativescript plugin, specifically in the line toaster.show (context, "Hello world");

**(Plugin Nativescript)**

```
var application = require("application");
var context = application.android.context;

module.exports = {
    showToast: function() {        
       var toaster = new com.example.toasterlibrary.ToasterMessage();        
        toaster.show(context,"Hello world");
    }
};
```

Finally, this is the file that the plugin uses, this is working properly but I'm including it to give more context

**(App Nativescript)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as ToasterMessage  from 'nativescript-toaster'

@Component({
    selector: "ns-items",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./items.component.html"
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        ToasterMessage.showToast();
    }
}
```

I expect that launch a toast message, but launch the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: toaster.show is not a function
```

This error is at the nativescript plugin after executing this command **tns run android**:

Comment: Did you try a clean build after placing the updated AAR where you converted show to be non-static method? Do you have the plugin in Git already? Between, there are plug-ins for toaster already. Moreover these apis can be accessed within JS runtime, you don't really have to build an AAR, just in case if you are not aware already.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I was missing a clean build.

I needed was to do a minimum integration test with a android sdk, I did it with the aar,  can i make the same with a sdk?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were missing the clean build.

Whenever you update the AAR file, you may have to perform a clean build otherwise the plugin / project may be pointing to the older version of your library.